# Is it possible to set up multiple cluster in spring data elastic search?

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

We have a use case where we want to use certain indices in different cluster so as to improve performance.
We are using java based configuration for elasticsearch.

```
@Log4j
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = ["com.as.core.repositories"])
class ElasticSearchConfig {

@Bean
ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
    Client client
    Settings settings


    InetSocketTransportAddress inetSocketTransportAddress = new InetSocketTransportAddress(
            Holders.config.grails.elasticsearch.transportClientIP as String,
            Holders.config.grails.elasticsearch.transportClientPort as Integer
    )

        settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
                .build()
        client = new TransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(inetSocketTransportAddress)



    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client)
    }
}
```

- Is there any way so that we can add configurations of a different elastic-search cluster?
- Spring data automatically creates indices in the specified cluster. How is the creation of indices managed in multi cluster application?

What I have googled is there is method `addTransportAddresses(inetSocketTransportAddress)` which allow us to add an array of elastic search server addresses.

- But how will we specify multiple cluster names?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents you from creating several clients to different clusters.

In your `ElasticSearchConfig` class, simply declare a second method `elasticsearchTemplate2()` which returns another instance of `ElasticsearchTemplate` embedding another `Client` to another cluster.

Then you call one method or the other depending on where you need to create your indices.

Comment: We don't call any method to create the indices. It gets automatically created.I created another method specifying different cluster details but automatically the one with methodName 'elasticsearchTemplate()' was being considered.

Comment: @Richa Where you able to solve your use case? We are having a similar scenario with Guice.